# Slug url без всяких редиректов

Tags: url, redirect, slug

На stackoverflow, и на других сайтах используется, как я понимаю, штука под названием slug url, текстовое описание страницы после кода (эта страница: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418314/slug-url-без-всяких-редиректов ) Я хочу сделать также, но не используя перенаправлений на основную страницу, так сделано у blizzard (например http://eu.battle.net/wow/ru/blog/18539917/тут-можно-написать-что-угодно ). Как технически это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Механизмы абсолютно идентичны, если не считать финальную проверку с перенаправлением.

По URL определяем конкретный кусок кода, который ответственен за рендеринг (обычно все строится по шаблону MVC, и определяется непосредственно контроллер). Чаще всего совпадения ищутся на основе регулярок, для этого в конфигурации задается таблица соответствий "регулярка-контроллер":

```
^wow/(?P<language>\w+)/blog/?$
    -> blog/index
^wow/(?P<language>\w+)/blog/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/?$
    -> blog/post
.*
    -> pages/show // catch-all, который возьмет на себя все URL, не подпадающие под предыдущие правила.
```

После этого роутер последовательно сравнивает текущий `REQUEST_URI` c каждой регуляркой и, в случае нахождения совпадения, отдает приложению идентификатор ответственного контроллера заодно с совпадениями из url (в данном случае это `language`, `id` и `slug`). Приложение запускает этот контроллер, передавая ему параметры. В данном случае контроллер будет использовать `id`, чтобы найти необходимую запись по этому самому `id`. И вот только на этом этапе начинаются различия: battle.net сразу выведет запись, не обращая внимания на `slug`, stackoverflow же проверит `slug` на совпадение с тем, который он считает правильными, и если ему что-то непонравится, то он перенаправит на нужную страницу. Делается это, очевидно, для поисковой оптимизации (для поисковика на battle.net может быть условно-бесконечное количество страниц с одним и тем же контентом, у stackoverflow только одна).

Таким образом, минимальная реализация этого шаблона подразумевает:

1. Создание таблицы соответствий регулярка-контроллер
2. Создание роутера, который будет по этой таблице проходиться
3. Создание приложения, которое все это запускает
4. И, наконец, создание самого контроллера, который будет обрабатывать запрос и искатьпо `id` запись.

Первые три пункта реализованы во всех фреймворках, которые вы найдете, прямо "из коробки". Продвинутые фреймворки умеют куда большее, чем просто сопоставлять url с регуляркой, и, соответственно, позволяют более гибкую настройку (примеры: [symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) - вплоть до специальных проверок на соответствие заголовков, [laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing) - разбиение по HTTP-методам из коробки).

Comment: Похоже, вы действительно понимаете, о чем речь. Проблема в том, что я - не очень :) Мне надо было точнее сформулировать вопрос. Допустим, я хочу сделать такое для нескольких статических страниц (не спрашивайте, зачем :) ), типа domain/1/текст-1 , domain/2/текст-2 и т.д. Я надеялся, что можно это реализовать с помощью htaccess, каких-нибудь mod_rewrite и подобных механизмов. Мне не нужно формировать динамически slug url.

Comment: @Alex, уточните задачу. Что именно должно отдавать страницы. Отдельный скрипт на каждую страницу? Один скрипт на все? Или должны отдаваться голые HTML-файлы?

Comment: вот смотрите. есть каталог 111, в нем лежит статическая страница, допустим index.html, при обращении по адресу "domain/111/любой-текст" выдается эта страница. Страница показывается при любом введенном тексте, который остается в строке адреса (или даже без текста, типа "domain/111/". Так сделано на battle.net. Мне не понятно, как это делается (здесь на SO редиректит на жестко заданный slug url, это уже не так интересно).

Comment: перевод документации Symfony по маршрутизации
https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть 2 варианта:

1) У вас статичные страницы. В таком случае для /someurl/page1/ вам нужно будет создать вложенные директории someurl/page1/ и положить туда index.html
Большинство веб-серверов по умолчанию сконфигурировано на поиск index.html в директории при обращении к ней.

2) У вас динамические страницы. Тогда обычно у приложения есть одна точка входа (например index.php) через которую проходят все запросы и роутинг разруливается у вас в приложении.
Для перенаправления запросов к входному скрипту в Apache используют mod_rewrite, у nginx же используется ngx_http_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в интернетах такое, делает, что мне нужно:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /111/index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

правда, в этом подкаталоге перестал работать редирект c "без-www" на www :(